# HiDPI problems with 4k monitor and 17.10

Tags: 17.10, scaling, 4k-monitor

**NOTE:** If anyone knows how to answer this, feel free as it will likely help others in the future. I ultimately returned the 4K monitor and got another 1080 monitor, which functions great. In any case, here is the original question:

Is there any way to scale things in a reasonable fashion yet with 17.10? I have a 24" 4k monitor and everything is TINY on it. I generally either have to lower the resolution to read anything, zoom in on text, etc.

I noticed that Wayland supports fractional scaling, but unfortunately my system refuses to launch Wayland. If I select it from the login screen it just goes blank, and then ultimately brings me back to the login screen. I have to use an X server or I can't even login! :(

Additionally, scaling to 200% is possible, but the display suffers serious performance problems, tearing, and so on. I have an nvidia GTX 1060 so there is no reason performance should be an issue.

I'm also using the vanilla gnome, as I had installed it prior to the 17.10 change where they sort of made gnome shell function like Unity.

Comment: NVIDIA cards don't work with Wayland.

Comment: Well that's good to know, though I find it odd that they choose not to support the cards that have THE best drivers and performance. I know it probably requires coordination with nvidia which is why they didn't. But where does that leave me with X?

Comment: I would really like an answer to this too. I'm struggling and unfortunately have little to offer for a solution.

Comment: I think this can be closed, as 17.10 is EOL now and there has been significant improvements made in the last versions, so the question is not relevant anymore.